# Google Map API for driving Distance Cost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, distance

Im currently writing an ios app which uses google map api's to measure driving distance between long and lat points. My question is to do with Google introducing payments on using their google map service, does using using the api to measure distance count as a use of google maps. i.e. will I only be able to do 25000 measurements per day before being changed by google to use the service?

I know 25000 is quite high and we probably wont go past that, but just want to know all use scenarios before locking it in.

Also am i correct in saying if i use the IPhone Map kit for an app i charge for ($.99 on itunes appstore) than I have to pay google 10k for the enterpise version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25k is for loading the api and not a direction. This is very high even when you do distance calculations. The api is the js-file that needs to be loaded client side and Google limited the download to 25k a day. It mean's if you can cache it per client you have virtually unlimited queries free. I don't think you have to pay 10k to Google in both cases and 10k is a lot of money.

Comment: Yeah i need to calculate the driving distance between two seperate pins that the user places on the Iphone MapKit MapView. So will be using both MapView (which is google) and also the distance api.

Comment: You do not require a enterprise license to use MapKit and to sell your app. You may want to look at the Terms of Service to make sure that you are complying, namely showing the driving directions on a map.

Comment: @Raven: I've fixed my answer. I mean you have virtually unlimited queries free if you don't have more then 25000 different downloads from the js file per day.

Comment: Is it possible to for my application to log the users locations and plot this on the mapview? Or is against google ToS?